# Web App stops working

Tags: javascript, android, timer

This question is a bit vague as I am not sure how to phrase it.  I fully accept this can be voted down but if anyone has an insight it would be most helpful.

I am trying to determine whether it is my web app code that is at fault or the inherit nature of Mobile Web apps (especially on Android devices).

I have this web app.

It has been designed using asp.net, C#, JavaScript and Jquery.

I have 1 page with 2 divs in it.
The 1st div shows a login page (i.e. Username and Password).
When logged in this div is hidden and the 2nd div is shown.

This 2nd div 'starts' a timer that downloads an image from my server every now and again.

I use the SetTimeout function and I recall it if there is no image ready to download or/and the image.src has finished its onload event.

I can look at this web app on my phone for hours and it will always work.

Then, I logoff (i.e. no timer is active) and the 1st div is shown.

I go to bed.

I wake up.

I go to my Android browser.

The web app shows the login div

I login

All OK.

{so the call to my server works}

But no images are downloaded.

I have put a visual counter in to show whether my timer is working.

It is not.

I refresh the page and relogin.  Everything works again.

Now, I can accept if it is my code but is it the way Android handles web apps?

Any suggestions would be grand.

I can post this code if anyone needs to see it,. But it is very simple and I did not want to obscure my question.

CODE#

In DIV 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#btnGoToLogin").click(function () {
            function StartRefresh() {
                try {
                    Start();
                    //display div 2
                    //hide div 1   
                }
                catch (err) {
                    $("#divVersion").html("1# " + err);
                }
            }            
        });
    });
</script>
```

In DIV 2

```
function Start() {
    try {
        if (timer4x4) window.clearTimeout(timer4x4);
        timer4x4 = window.setTimeout(swapImages4x4, 100);
    }
    catch (err) {
        $("#divVersion").html("1# " + err);
    }
}

function Stop() {
    if (timer4x4) window.clearTimeout(timer4x4);
}

function setImageSrc1x1(src) {
    live1x4.src = src;
    Start();
}

function swapImages4x4() {
    try {
        serverImage1x4.onload = function () {
            setImageSrc1x1(serverImage1x4.src);
        };

        serverImage1x4.onerror = function () {
            Start();
        };
        GetImageStatus();
    }
    catch (err) {
        $("#divVersion").html("2# " + err);
    }
}

function GetImageStatus() {
     serverImage1x4.src = url + '/Mobile/LiveXP.ashx?Alias=' + Alias + '&camIndex=' + camIndex + '&Guid=' + createGuid();

}


    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#btnExitLogin").click(function () {
            function ExitDiv2() {
                try {
                    Stop();
                    //display div 1
                    //hide div 2   
                }
                catch (err) {
                    $("#divVersion").html("1# " + err);
                }
            }            
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code it's difficult to say where is the problem, but try this 3 approaches:

1) Is this happening if you log off, than log back in again, without leaving the activity?
If so, you should dig in your javascript more

2) Is this happening if you log off, put app in background, than bring it to foreground, log back in? If so look at on pause on resume events

3) It's only happening if you log out, put the app in background leave it for a longer period, I will look more in the onStop

E

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your thoughts. Now I appreciate my JavaScript experience is not that great but are not 'Activities' related to native apps?  Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry my fault miss read, I only read WebApp, and I thought about WebView app not WebApp trough browser, please ignore point 2 and 3, it will be somewhere in point 1

Comment: Hi, thats OK.  Regarding 1). It only happens if my Android is not being used overnight }(aka long period of time) without any activity anywahere else The web app could be to the focus or could be in the background.  Makes no difference.  Like I said b4, the script is very simple and I have error handlers everywhere :)

Comment: Sure. Pls give me a few mins

Comment: I cannot see where you assign any value to tmrInterval. Like a first idea I will try to pass the interval value trough the start function each time it is called, instead of using a global value.

Comment: Ah, sorry it should be 100. I will give your suggestion a go though I will not know anything until tomorrow :)

Comment: And one more think, why do you have 2 functions with the same name? In both div1 and div2 you have a function Start, rename one of them. Tobe honest, from what you have posted I do not see the sense of function Start in div 1, so I will totally get rid of it, do the display, hide, and call function start which is defined in DIV2.

Comment: hi, it was a copy and paste error. It has nothing to do with the behaviour/issue. But thanks for pointing that out]

Comment: This was why I did not want to initially post the code.  It has to do with how Android deals with timers when the web app is not used for sometime

Comment: Well Android will handle timers like any other browser, I know it is hard to find the mistake and sometimes you spend days going in circles and not seeing the obvious, but there must be a small flaw in the process, just really have to find it. (And I'm speaking from own experience here)

Comment: All very true. :) I DO know when I wrote an Android native app that you have to run the app on a 'special (cannot remember the correct name)' worker thread to make sure that app does not become idle if you want it to always be on-line.  I believe this is to do with how Android OS pushes inactive app to the bottom of the stack.  Anyway the search continues!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you stopped the timeout when you logged out.
So when you login again, you start it again.
But something might fail with the start after the next login.
I guess it's definitively your Javascript code.

> (...) but is it the way Android handles web apps?

I guess the automatic lock screen is one thing, that could cause timers to pause / stop.
You didn't use your device over the night, so I guess it locked itself. That might cause the browser to stop draining your battery.

E.g. when your screen locks, you won't be able to watch Youtube videos.

That's what I know about it. Hope that helped a bit.

Comment: Hi, all comments are welcome. The only flaw with that argument is that   I have tested logging on and off and on again and it works. The 'Start' function has an errorhandler that traps all errors and nothing appears. But I really appreciate your thoughts on this. Thanks